# How to install GRUB with dualboot in Legacy mode?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub, uefi, grub-legacy

I have a problem with my laptop, I have Windows 10 and Parrot Home OS (a Debian based OS) in other partition, yesterday when I installed Parrot, the installer noticed me that the only thing that failed in the installation was the Grub bootloader, and what a pain...

with some research now I can initiate Parrot with Super Grub2 Disk utility in a pendrive, but I can´t access Windows yet and I want to reinstall correctly Grub in my HDD.

Yes, my notebook have UEFI, **but I use the LEGACY MODE, and the partitions are in MSDOS tables...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I find the solution to my problem:
I downloaded the Boot-Repair-Disk, that is a Lubuntu based distro that have "boot repair" utility and other interesting utilities, this solves my problem in less than 5 minutes...

I see that i'm not the only person with this problem installing Parrot OS, it seems to be a bug of the Debian-installer or something in Parrot, but well, I want to share this solution if there is someone that found this entry and need help:

This is the download page of the utility: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/
Just burn in a USB stick with Unetbootin or Etcher, start and boot in your PC, then follow the instructions of the Boot-Repair, you will need internet connection too.
When the repair/installation of grub finished, restart, you will see the beutiful Grub, start your system, open a terminal and type "sudo grub-update", and voila, Grub installed and fully configured.